# Virtual Machine

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I just installed local by flywheel on my windows 10 machine but virtual box could not launch local and instead I am getting this error below. Please how do I resolve this issue?

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine local-by-flywheel.

Could not open the medium 'C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\local-by-flywheel\disk.vmdk'.

VMDK: inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table in 'C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\local-by-flywheel\disk.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).

VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file 'C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\local-by-flywheel\disk.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run VirtualBox as administrator. To do so, exit all instances of VirtualBox first. Then reopen as:

- Right click on VirtualBox
- Click "Run As Administrator"

Hopefully this will resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Junaid Ahmed. This did not solve the problem. I still get the same error that I posted here.